# VirtualBox optimization

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have Ubuntu 64-bit machine (2 core, 4GB RAM, not Core i(3/5/7).

It's running 64-bit VirtualBox.

Inside of VirtualBox runs Windows 7.

Inside Windows 7 runs one pretty heavy .NET program.

All this is performing little slow.

(and I totally understand why) - but is there anything I can do to improve performance?

(thought to switch to Linux Mint - but read its specs and it seems same as Ubuntu, thought to disable some Windows graphic effects, but not sure if that will be enough, would be nice to hear some ideas).

Comment: The late models *are* the Core ix processors (unless you're talking about server or AMD CPUs). To the point: How many base memory and processors do you have allocated to the VM? Do you have VT-x/AMD-V enabled? Nested Paging? 3D acceleration? 2D acceleration? Do you have Guest Additions installed? What exactly does this *pretty heavy* program do?

Comment: Which processor do you have? Does it support virtualization? Is Virtualization enabled?

2 Core says nothing, do you mean Core 2 Duo? Which model?

Comment: sorry I meant NOT Core ix. It's 2 core AMD.

Comment: I gave VM as much as I could - 50% RAM (2Gb); 1 processor (tried to do 2 but that requires some settings in BIOS, and I'm doing it remotely so need some software fix); no 2D|3D acceleration(should I?)